# How do you overload operator>> if you are just recreating the ifstream class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, ifstream

My teacher wanted us to learn the ifstream class and how it works. She gave us homework to create a FileStream wrapper class that is templated to work with anything and can take in anything that's in the file.

I have written everything except I can't get it to compile because I don't know how to write the `>>` operator and keep getting errors for it. This is what I have so far:

```
template<class A>
ifstream& operator >>(FileStream<A> fs, A& x){
  fs>>x;
  return fs;
}
```

In the main she is using to check our work it is called like this:

```
FileStream<Word> input;
Word temp; //word is a class we created to manipulate strings in certain ways 

while(input>> temp){
  cout<<temp<<endl;
}
```

If anyone could help me out I would be most grateful. I've been working on this for 2 days and I can't get it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
FileStream<T>& operator >> (FileStream<T>& fs, T& value) {
  value = fs.readValueFromStream();
  return fs;
}
```

Your method should look something like the above. Highlights:

(Note that I've renamed `A` to `T` and `x` to `value`. `T` is the usual name for generic template arguments, and `value` is a bit more descriptive than `x`.)

1. Accepts a `FileStream<T>&` reference. The `&` ensures that you work with the original stream object and not a copy.
2. Returns a `FileStream<T>&` reference, not an `ifstream`.
3. Rather than doing `fs>>x` in the method, which would just be a recursive call to the very method we're in, you need to write code to actually read an item from the stream and put it into `value`. This should use some method of your `FileStream` class. I wrote `value = fs.readValueFromStream()` but this could be anything.

In this way `operator >>` serves as syntactic sugar. The real work is done by the `value = fs.readValueFromStream()` line (or whatever code you actually write there).

Comment: but then what is that readItemFromStream() method? Do you re-open the file and read from it as a normal ifstream?

Comment: @user1828256 Good question. Perhaps you could post it as a separate follow-up question, linking back to this one. I don't think I'll be able to answer it properly tonight.

Comment: i actually just made an array in my constructor loaded everything into that and now my >> operator read from that array and delete the first object in it untill no more